# CSS a miss behavior

Tags: html, css

I has a website. which show strange behavior on my page.

Here is my website the sample design http://ryugaku.babonmultimedia.com/assets/templates/html/tabing.html
And here is the sample which already developed in CMS format http://ryugaku.babonmultimedia.com/products/kickstart

please check at this part under `<div class="godelpage">`

```
<a href="http://ryugaku.babonmultimedia.com/products/kickstart" class="" id="productLink19">
    <img src="/assets/images/tab/tab-kickStart-on.png" alt="KickStart" title="KickStart">
</a>
```

From the sample page the `<a>` width is has shorter width than `<a>` in live site for the CMS.
How can this be happen?
I check from FireBug that's two part two part of `<a>` has same CSS property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `float:left` to this class and than see

```
.godelpage a {
margin: 0 3px 0 0;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: it fix it, but i still wondering why the sample can done it without `float:left` :(

Comment: which cms you are using? not have very solid reason but may me some cms classes or properties conflicting.

Comment: i use modx, but the CMS i think didn't afect the CSS since its produce same HTML.

Comment: as suggestion (not related to the css): page also having script errors, please look @ those also.